# Update DIV content on click without directly knowing its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building 2D tile game map. Each tile is a div in 2D array (var tiles = []). Below is the function which builds a tile based on some arguments defined somewhere else:

```
function Tile(rnd, px, py, nid) {
var self = this;
var _types = ["grass","forest","hills","swamp","forest", "mountains"];

var height = 60;
var width = 60;
var tileID = nid // new numeric tile id

var id = "tile_"+px+py+rnd; // old tile ID
var x = px;
var y = py;

var type = _types[rnd];
var img = 'img/maptiles/'+type+'.png';

this.Draw = function() {
    var div = $("<div class='tile'></div>");
    div.attr('id',tileID).data('type',type).data('x',x).data('y',y);
    div.get(0).tile = self;
    div.css({top:height*y, left:width*x});
    div.css({"background":"url('"+img+"')"});
    div.appendTo('#map-content');
};


this.Alert = function() {
    alert("Tile type: "+type+". Tile ID: "+tileID+" ");
};

this.Move = function(){ // moves player to available tile, in this case if player stands to a tile before the clicked one
    alert("start move! Tile type: "+type+". Tile ID: "+tileID+" ");
    if (playerPosition === tileID - 1) {
        $("#player").remove();
        $("#????")").append('<img id="player" src="Pictures/maptiles/player.png" />');
        playerPosition = tileID;
        alert("Player position now: " + playerPosition);

    }


};
```

}

As a result I end up with m x n map made of divs each with a unique numeric ID starting with 1. I know that using numeric IDs for elements is(was?) frowned upon, though HTML5 specs do not actually prohibit this anymore.

Now what I want to do is to place a player icon (player.png) depending on player's position. Starting position is 1 and I am using tiles (aka divs) numeric IDs to calculate legal moves (can move only to bordering tiles).

When a tile is clicked this.Move is called. Its purpose is to check if player can move on a clicked tile (just one IF statement for now to test) and must remove player.png and redraw it on the clicked div.

Here I run into a problem since I need to somehow use the tileID (which is equal to Div ID) to tell browser to append the DIV which is belong clicked (as I obviously do not write a function for every div on the field). I think that since I can get the DIV id on click I can use it somehow.

I tried to experiment with this.div.id:eq("+tileID+") but with no luck.

UPD:

Adding click handler as requested. Note this is within var Map, which is responsible for building the map, rendering and handling some user input:

```
var Map = new function() {
var maxHorz = 20;
var maxVert = 5;

var tiles = [];
this.init = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<maxVert; i++) {
        tiles[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j<maxHorz; j++) {
            tiles[i][j] = new Tile(Math.random()*6|0, j, i, tileID++);
        }
    }  

    Render();
    Setup();
};

this.GetMap = function() {
    return tiles;
};

var Render = function() {
    $.each(tiles, function(k,v){
        $.each(v, function(k,t){
            t.Draw(); 
        });
    });
};

var Setup = function(){
    $('#map-content').on('click','div.tile', function(e){
         //var tile = tiles[$(this).data('y')][$(this).data('x')];
         this.tile.Move();
    });
}

this.Redraw = function(x,y) {

};
```

}

Map.init();

Comment: Why do you assign `this` to `self` and then never use `self`?

Comment: *When a tile is clicked this.Move is called.* Can you show the click-handler for more clarity?

Comment: Added click handler (copied all map building code as well)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found, finally :)

```
$('#player').detach().appendTo($('#'+tileID))
```

Comment: `.appendTo()` automatically removes the element from its actual place, so you can make it short: `$('#player').appendTo($('#'+tileID))`.